# Perform an action on each file during installApp phase of Gradle build

Tags: java, build, gradle

Here is a minimal build.gradle file I'm using.

```
apply plugin: 'application'

installApp {
  eachFile {
    println "$it.name"
    loadProperties(it)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to load properties into some placeholders in a properties file located in `src/dist/bin`. This technique works fine if the properties file is in `src/main/resources` and I replace `installApp` with `processResources` which I am doing in another project within the build.

The `println` isn't printing anything so it makes sense the placeholders aren't replaced but I don't understand why it's not iterating through all the files the installApp task is copying.

Running this as `./gradlew clean installApp` using gradle 1.10.

It appears that the installApp task doesn't run closure passed to the eachFile function. Here is a complete build.gradle file that demonstrates this behavior

```
apply plugin: "application"

mainClassName = "test.Test"

installApp {
  eachFile {
    println "$it.name"
  }
}
```

I run `gradle clean installApp -i`

and around the installApp section get

```
:installApp (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:installApp
Executing task ':installApp' (up-to-date check took 0.011 secs) due to:
  Output file /Users/joshbrackett/Documents/workspace/gtest/build/install/gtest has changed.
  Output file /Users/joshbrackett/Documents/workspace/gtest/build/install/gtest/bin/gtest has been removed.
  Output file /Users/joshbrackett/Documents/workspace/gtest/build/install/gtest/lib/gtest.jar has been removed.
:installApp (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.748 secs.
```

Comment: If this prints nothing, chances are that no files are being installed. Perhaps the task is already `UP-TO-DATE`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser - I've updated my question to include that I'm doing a clean. I've even manually deleted the install directory to be sure and the files (start scripts/propery file) are being moved but the property file still has the placeholders.

Comment: I don't really understand how you are trying to do the substitution. In any case, if the `println` doesn't take effect, the only logical conclusion I have is that nothing is getting synced.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks for trying to help. For simplification we can forget about the properties not being updated. I think we can agree that the file names should be printed though. It's as if the eachFile function isn't being called or the closure passed isn't being executed when used with installApp. As I mentioned earlier in the question this works when using processResources. In regards to your second statement how does that follow when I can remove the install directory and it is recreated with the start scripts and jar in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated your issue. I suspect this is a bug. While we investigate further, here is a workaround that worked for me.

make your `eachFile` call on the `applicationDistribution` copySpec rather than the `installApp` task.

```
applicationDistribution.eachFile {
   println "$it.name"
}
```

I suspect that this is what you want to do anyway, since then it will also be used by the dist tasks.

BTW you may also find that the `expand` method is of interest http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#expand(java.util.Map)

Answer (score 1):

This has changed again in Gradle 2.3 apparently. Now using `applicationDistribution` doesn't work and you need to use `installDist` instead.